# Disallow a folder to import files from another, but still allow other files to import those files

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

How can eslint be configured to disallow a folder to import files from another folder, but still allow other files in the repo to import those files

I.e. given the following folder structure:

```
/core/services
/core/models
/core/interfaces
```

Can I configure a rule to disallow files in `/core/services/**/*` from being imported by `/core/models/**/*`, while allowing them to be imported by folders outside of `/core/models/**/*`?

Imports will use relative paths, so I would want to exclude the relative paths in particular. Absolute paths or root relative paths are an unlikely scenario

Sample import in my project from an interface:

```
import { Entity } from '../../models/Entity';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished via [eslint-plugin-boundaries package](https://github.com/javierbrea/eslint-plugin-boundaries)

After installing and enabling the package (see their documentation), configure your .eslintrc.json with:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "boundaries/elements": [
        {
            "type": "core models",
            "pattern": "core/models/*"
        },
        {
            "type": "core services",
            "pattern": "core/services/*"
        }
        ...
    ]
},
```

And also your rules:

```
"rules": {
    "boundaries/element-types": [2, {
        "default": "allow",
        "rules": [
            {
                "from": "core models",
                "disallow": ["core interfaces"]
            }
        ]
    }],
```